# Sqoop loading null values

Tags: hive, sqoop

Using sqoop i am extracting data from teradata and loading in hive,in teradata there is only 100 rows but in hive i am seeing 2000 rows ,some null values are loaded.when i reseach on this issue i came to know that issue is because of string columns in table and it will resolve by adding --hive-drop-import-delims parameter but with teradata and cloudera this parameter having compatibility issue.

Example:
To debug the issue i have just extracted one row from source and loaded in HDFS. Below you can see line is braked into two lines and loading as two row in hive.In teradata one of the columns in varchar(100) i think it causing row to break into two lines.Is there any way to make into single row.

Output Data:

111111,09999,2017-12-17,2014-01-15,2014-02-25,vivn,Open,51,rajesh,
null,2014-03-19 14:18:36.000,2014-03-19 14:18:36.000,I

```
sqoop import  --connect jdbc:teradata://xxxxxxx/DATABASE=bf_core,LOGMECH=LDAP,CHARSET=UTF8,TMODE=ANSI --username xxxx -password xxxxx --table MTR_tbl --where "mtr_id=1111111"  --target-dir /data/history/MTR_XCL_LST9  --hive-import --hive-database dev_history --hive-table MTR_XCL_LST9 --split-by Mtr_Id --create-hive-table -m 1
```

Comment: What is the error after adding `--hive-drop-import-delims` ?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Detected incompatible parameters: Unsupported parameter:--hive-drop-import-delims                                     at com.cloudera.connector.teradata.options.OptionsCompatibility.throwIllegalArgumentException(OptionsCompatibility.java:266)

Comment: There may have  \n or \r in the varchar(100) column, which is causing this. I faced similar issue with xml datatype of DB2. But `--hive-drop-import-delims` worked for me. What is your sqoop version?

Comment: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.7.0..--hive-drop-import-delims parameter is not working with my version

Comment: Please try import command wirth `--driver <JDBC driver class name>` and `--hive-drop-import-delims`

Comment: could you please help me how to get the class name,i mean where to check

Comment: Add `--driver com.ncr.teradata.TeraDriver` and `--hive-drop-import-delims` in your command.

Comment: After adding mention parameter getting below error Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.teradata.tdgss.jtdgss.TdgssConfigApi.GetMechanisms(Unknown Source)
        at com.teradata.tdgss.jtdgss.TdgssManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.teradata.tdgss.jtdgss.TdgssManager.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.GenericTeraEncrypt.getGSSM(GenericTeraEncrypt.java:623)
        at

Comment: Which Teradata jars have you added in sqoop/lib?

Comment: Try with `--driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver`. I am assuming you added `terajdbc4.jar`, `tdgssconfig.jar` in the sqoop/lib